# BIP 44 master private key sign tx

Tags: bitcoind, bip32-hd-wallets, bip

I have this Bip44 path implemented

```
m / purpose' / coin_type' / account' / change / address_index
```

Is it possible to use the Master private key to sign all the tx
ie. Bitcoin TX, Etherum TX

or do I have to get the asset based private keys for each asset and sign the tx's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or I have to get the asset based private keys for each asset and sign the tx's ?

Yes, you can't sign transactions using the master private key. Sign each transaction using the derived private keys.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, btw Is it possible to use m/0/k path and sign tx using the master private key ?

Comment: No, use this: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#private-parent-key--private-child-key

Answer (score 0):

you can't sign tx with the parent node xprv which are extension keys, so you have to use the address keys (which don't have chaincode in the key, standard private key)